# How to get path to file under vendor in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I want to parse an `ini` file placed under the `vendor` directory.

How can I get the path to this file?

**For Example:**

In `src/Acme/TestBundle/Repository/UserRepository.php` I have

```
$file = parse_ini_file(FILE_PATH);
```

How do I set `FILE_PATH` to reach `vendor/test/lib/conf.ini`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other solution is correct but it can be even shorter *(plus this should be the way to go in the current symfony version)*:

```
public function setup()
{
    $rootDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
    $filePath = $rootDir.'/../vendor/test/lib/conf.ini';
    $file = parse_ini_file($filePath);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provided info what kind of test do you use, but you need to get the container and get kernel.root_dir from there

For WebTestCase:

```
public function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();
        $rootDirectory = $kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
        $filePath = $rootDirectory.'/../vendor/test/lib/conf.ini;
...
}
```